How to remove drop database permission from db_owner?
Is it possible to remove the DROP DATABASE permission from db_owner? How to achieve this?

No, you can not.


Except for the public database role, the permissions assigned to the fixed database roles can't be changed.
Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all configuration and maintenance activities on the database, and can also DROP the database in SQL Server.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-database-roles
If you want to restrict user's behavior, create a user-define db-role, GRANT or DENY permissions on it, and add the user to this role.

If user has the role with deny drop database permission, and user is also db_owner. Then does this work (prevent drop?)

@variable Bypass the permission check if the login is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role or if the user is the dbo user in the current database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#general-steps-of-the-algorithm, but it also said in an official article that permissions it too complex to understand, you'd better test it to verify the result is what you want after you made changes.

as already answered by Roger Kong you can't remove the specific cant drop the database from the db_owner group.
However, what I have been doing in similar situations is to create a server side trigger that does something else and does not allow to drop the database.
Here for instance I don't allow to create a linked server, using a server side trigger. it definitely works.
in this answer here you can see the DDL Statements That Have Server or Database Scope and this list includes the drop database command, so it is possible.
Just as an idea for you to consider, you might be able to track drop database and other commands using extended events. It will require a bit of work to get the functionality you want though.
